# Scraping content from yellowpage and write them to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to scrape names and phone numbers of a certain search from yellowpage traversing multiple pages. The scraper has the ability to collect all the links connected to all the names. Once the links are collected, the scraper goes to the target page to parse the name and website address. Finally, it will produce a csv file with data filled-in. Although the scraper is doing it's job errorlessly, I'm little dubious as to whether I used the best way to write items in a csv file. Any betterment to the pattern will be highly appreciated.

Here is what I've written:

```
import requests
import csv
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=+Injury+Law+Attorneys&geo_location_terms=California"

def get_links(session,link): 
    session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
    res = session.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select(".info h2 a[data-analytics]"):
        get_info(session,urljoin(url,items.get("href")))

    nextpage = soup.select_one("a.next")
    if nextpage:  #If there is no more next page link, it should break
        nexturl = urljoin(link,nextpage.get("href"))
        print(nexturl)        #check to see which page I'm on
        get_links(session,nexturl)  #supply the newly produced next page link to grab the next one

def get_info(session,tlink):
    session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
    res = session.get(tlink)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    name = soup.select_one("#main-header .sales-info h1").get_text(strip=True)
    website = soup.select_one("#main-header a.website-link").get("href") if soup.select_one("#main-header a.website-link") else ""
    print(name,website)
    writer.writerow([name,website])  #writing data in a csv file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("yellowpageinfo.csv","w",newline="") as infile: #creating a csv file to write populated results
        writer = csv.writer(infile)
        writer.writerow(['Name','Website'])
        with requests.Session() as session:
            get_links(session,url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description and your code don't seem to match. In the code I don't see anything related to phone numbers. I also don't understand what "The scraper has the ability to collect all the links connected to all the names." means. With that said, I'm not sure if any of my critique is valid, but here I go any way.

To answer your question about writing to csv, I think you are doing it right. In fact, you are doing it exactly as shown in documentation, so no issues here.

Now I'd like to get into details.

## Minor issues

- #### Format your code

  Run `autopep8` and `isort` on your code before submitting it. Makes it easier to quickly scan through it.
- #### Use consistent string quoting

  It doesn't matter whether you use single or double quotes. What matters is that you pick one and stick with it.
- #### Get rid of useless comments

  Consider:

  ```
  writer.writerow([name, website])  # writing data in a csv file
  ```

  This comment is virtually useless, because the code right beside it says the same thing. Comments like this explain nothing  and should be deleted.
- #### Variable naming

  - Spare extra characters to rename `res` to `response`
  - Avoid generic names (e.g. rename `item` to something like `search_result`)
  - Use underscore to separate individual words in variable name (e.g. `nextpage` →`next_page`)

  Good variable names often eliminate the need for comments. Effort spent on coming up with concise and descriptive names goes a long way towards improving readability.

## More substantial issues

- This line is way too long.

  ```
   website = soup.select_one("#main-header a.website-link").get("href") if soup.select_one("#main-header a.website-link") else ""
  ```

  Consider rewriting it as an ordinary `if` statement. Save the result of `soup.select_one(...)` into a variable to avoid repeated function call.
- Use of recursion in `get_links` is confusing. Consider rewriting it using a `while` loop.

## Some things I might have misunderstood

- There doesn't seem be any need to use `requests.Session` and on top of that reset headers before every call to `get`. If you really need a persistent session, it'd be a good idea to leave a comment explaining why.
- In your code you seem to be only grabbing name and website for each search result. If that's the case, loading the details page for each result is redundant as all desired information is present in the search results themselves.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Nice first answer! Regarding `requests.Session`: this is not a session in the sense of you get a session ID and so on. This just means the connection to the server is kept alive and re-used for subsequent requests, which makes multiple requests to the same server faster.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! From the documentation on `requests.Session` I got the impression that its primary purpose is to persist cookies across multiple requests, but now I know better.

Comment: That *is* one other usecase for it (in addition to persisting other attributes of the request so you don't have to set them again every time).